# How dangerous it is to download a file, even for anti-virus scanning

Tags: virus, malware, anti-virus, exploit

Can anti-virus to run the malware in the file while checking the file (for example, the technology of buffer overflow)? If can, how then to check files for malware that you want to download from the Internet, so that viruses do not run on your computer? I'm also wondering how likely it is today that a downloaded file before you scan it with an antivirus and run it could be harmful (including buffer overflow for OS)?

Comment: There are several online virus scanning tools available that you could use. [Kaspersky VirusDesk](https://virusdesk.kaspersky.com/) is one example.

Answer (score 1):

Malware has to be launched to do bad things to your PC, and anti-malware apps inspect files in a special way which does not let them execute.

I have not been able to find any reliable data regarding the proportion of files available for download which are dangerous. Therefore, to protect yourself:

1. Don't open any file which is [executable](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/e/execfile.htm) before you scan it.
2. This includes any Microsoft Office file and [WMV](https://fileinfo.com/extension/wmv) files.
3. Since JavaScript can be launched within a web browser, limit your browser's ability to run [JavaScript](https://www.howtogeek.com/138865/htg-explains-should-you-disable-javascript/) from unknown websites. Check the extensions for your web browser for JavaScript blockers.
4. Avoid dodgy websites, file sharing websites, and websites that have a history of being hosed by malware. Yeah, looking at you, [Make-A-Wish Foundation](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/wish-foundation-website-infected-crypto-025429201.html).
5. Let your anti-malware apps automatically update when new definitions are available. For recommendations regarding anti-malware apps, or any other kind of app, please post your questions at the Stack Exchange [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site.
6. If available, install [Intel SGX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Guard_Extensions).
7. If you absolutely positively have to run something you don't trust, run it in a [virtualized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization) copy of your OS, in a [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine).
8. Back up your system on a regular basis so you can easily restore it back to a running condition.
9. Back up your data much more often than that. A [grandfather-father-son](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup_rotation_scheme) rolling backup is one way to do it, but decide for yourself how to protect your data.
10. Back up up data you create yourself (documents, things you write and create) and put them [offsite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-site_data_protection) into a cloud account every single day. Google, Microsoft, Apple, and Dropbox among others give free cloud storage.
11. When backing up to the cloud, [encrypt your data](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-encrypt-data-storing-it-cloud-and-why-you-should) first before you send it. [7-zip](https://7-zip.org) ([reviewed](http://www.donationcoder.com/legacy/Reviews/Archive/ArchiveTools/index.html)) ([another review](https://kikizas.net/en/apps.7z.html)) ([tutorial](https://www.top-windows-tutorials.com/free-zip/)) is Open Source and allows you to encrypt files while you archive them, either in a GUI interface or at the [command line](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/index.htm).  For example, this 7Zip [command](https://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples) makes an encrypted backup (with the password p@sSW0RD) of all files in and under your home directory in Windows, and encrypts the headers so file names can't be seen without the password:

> 7za a -t7z backall.7z -mhe c:\users\YOURUSERNAME\ -pP@sSW0RD

Comment: There are some kinds of malware that are included in non-executable files.  For instance, MS Word and MS Office file macros used to be a huge problem, and remain a problem now.  The rest of the list is good ideas.

Comment: Please see item 2 in the list.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, you can open the Downloads window and paste in a suspicious URL, and it will be downloaded directly.  Similarly, you can use a file download manager program or Curl to download without involving a web browser.  Be aware that you can also get an infection from just visiting a malicious page in a browser.

Some more ideas for reducing chance of infecting your PC :

A )  Create a Virtual Machine.

B )  Have a second physical machine, just for visiting problem sites.  It's best to have nothing important on this machine, and put it in a DMZ on your local network.  This is inferior to a virtual machine, because you can't revert to a snapshot.

C )  Don't visit the sites you know are bad.